# JQuery crashes the page when loading autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I'm having an array with possible values that I would like jQuery to autocomplete from. This array is very big. It has more than 1000 records inside. I'm using jQuery so I can be auto-completing from these possible values but it's taking so long that the page eventually crashes. 
This is my jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".postal-code-autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: postal_codes,
        delay: 0
    });
});
```

Any suggestion for optimization ?

EDIT: I made it work with minLength:3 but something weird happens. When I enter all 5 digits and it finds the value, it makes a drop down list with multiple rows and only one record, the one I chose. how can I avoid this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Remote option detailed in the documentation;

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Loading many values at once will obviously lock-up the browser, using the remote option will allow only loading a filtered sub-set of the data, based on what the user has typed